# How to make a shiny module for displaying a button conditionally?

Tags: r, shiny

The goal is to have a shiny module `ui1.R` activating the submit button only when something is typed in `lsuId`. The current code doesn't retrieve any errors, but it seems it never calls `toggleState`.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
htmlOutput("page")
```

**server.R**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
Logged <-  FALSE

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$"ui1Output-confirm", {
    Logged <<- T
  })

  observe({
input$"ui1Output-confirm"
    if (Logged == FALSE) {
      output$page <- renderUI({ 
        ui1Output('ui1Output') 
      })
      output$lsuId <- renderText({ input$lsuId })
    }
    if (Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({ ui2 })
    }
  })
  callModule(ui1,'ui1') 
})
```

**ui1.R**

```
library(shinyjs)

ui1Output <-  function(id, label = "ui1") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    titlePanel("Form"),
    div(textInput(ns("lsuId"), "This has to be filled", ""),
      actionButton(ns("confirm"), "Submit", class = "btn-primary")
    )
  ))
}

ui1 <- function(input, output, session) {
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "confirm", condition = F)
  observeEvent(input$lsuId!="", {
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "confirm", condition = T)
  })
}
```

**ui2.R**

```
ui2<-  shinyUI(fluidPage(
 div("well done!")
))
```

**global.R**

```
source('ui1.R') #login page
source('ui2.R')
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would approach this one:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(

    fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                    align = 'center',
                    h1('Conditional Submit Button'))),

    fluidRow(column(width = 12,
                    align = 'center',
                    textInput(inputId = 'text.field',
                              label = 'What is your greatest fear?',
                              value = ''),
                    uiOutput('submit.button')))
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    output$submit.button <-
      renderUI(expr = if (nchar(input$text.field)) {
        submitButton()
      } else {
        NULL
      })

  }
)
```

This approach doesn't use `shinyjs`, which I think is a positive (fewer dependencies), but I don't know if there's some reason you are interested in doing it with `shinyjs` that isn't stated in your question.

Here, ui.R simply has a `textInput` UI element with inputId `'text.field'` and a promise that another UI element will be rendered in server.R called `'submit.button'`.

In server.R, `output$submit.button` is set to `NULL` if the number of characters in `input$text.field` is 0, and set to `submitButton()` otherwise.

Comment: Does your solution keeps the enabled/disabled effect of the button? I was trying to keep the button there just in 2 different fashions.

Answer (score 0):

```
observe({
  if (is.null(input$lsuId) || input$lsuId == "") {
    shinyjs::disable("submit")
  } else {
    shinyjs::enable("submit")
  }
})
```